# Displaying an ABPeoplePickerNavigatorController within an existing UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app where I've a `UINavigationController` in a popover that displays some information. The root item contains a button showing a related Contact. I'd like to press the contact button and display the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`. I've got this code to do it:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *contactController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:contactController animated:YES];
```

When I push the button, however, I get this error: **Pushing a navigation controller is not supported**.

So: is there a way to either access the views within the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` (using `topViewController` or `visibleViewController` both give an error), or an alternate way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to show the NavigationController. The problem for you is that you can only push a view in your controller and not a whole navigationController:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *controller = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the controll
controller.peoplePickerDelegate = self;


NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];
controller.displayedProperties = properties;

// showing the picker
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

U can use the properties part or not. U also have to implement the Delegate protocol.